# Trying to restore an external USB SSD that got unplug unsafely

Tags: debian, data-recovery, usb-drive

I'm running Debian, and the SSD is formatted with NTFS. I'm trying to at least get back the data on it if it's still there.

It is not recognized with the `fdisk -l`. And it's apparently unable to be detected by the system.

Here's the output of the `dmesg` command:

```
[   40.241903] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   88.378502] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  293.776598] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  293.776603] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  293.776605] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  353.948036] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  353.948040] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  353.948041] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  353.948549] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  353.948552] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[  404.835068] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  404.835073] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#19 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 00 00 04 00
[  415.059057] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  415.059060] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#19 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  415.225329] sd 8:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  415.225347] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  415.225351] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  415.225359] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  415.225364] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[  415.225366] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  415.225373] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[  415.263086] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  664.193579] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  712.330935] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  915.743226] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  915.743230] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  915.743232] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  975.914872] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  975.914876] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  975.914878] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  975.915430] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  975.915433] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 1027.423926] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1027.423931] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#25 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 00 00 04 00
[ 1037.651350] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1037.651356] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#25 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1037.821667] sd 8:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1037.821694] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1037.821698] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 1037.821707] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1037.821713] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1037.821715] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1037.821722] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
[ 1037.859525] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: If NTFS, you need your Windows repair flash dirve. You can try chkdsk to see if that will repair it or use Windows tools to scan drive. From LInux you can try photorec. Thats a long process depending & size and amount of data. It also does not recover full filename, just extension. Some Windows tools may recover with full file name. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: @oldfred read the logs a bit more carefully!

Answer (score 1):

Your disk or its controller have a hardware defect: they take a long long time to initialize, and when it's done, they report a block size of 0 bytes and if these, the drive reports to have 0.

That's nothing any software on Linux or windows can fix. Unless this is a severe bug within the SSD firmware that can be fixed with a firmware update, you'll have to assume both your data and your SSD are gone. Sorry.

However, USB converters are probe to be very cheap. So maybe just opening your external SSD enclosure, of it was designed for that, and connecting the containers SSD by other means is a solution.

Comment: you're right the tools given in comments can't do anything, i'll try a usb converters and i'll keep you updated when i received it. Thanks for your idea !